# gcloud commands not working in crontab -e?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, cron, gcloud

I have few projects running in my google cloud projects and I am trying to stop them at specific time and start at specific time.

I created a script file for stopping `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
gcloud compute instances stop instance1
```

now I tried `crontab -e` and added this,

```
30 01 1-31 1-12 1-5 /home/user/test.sh >> /var/log/test.log
```

But this didn't stop my gcp instance and also didn't create any log file.

#### update,

I am just confused about the timings

```
00 10 * * 1-5 start.sh
00 01 * * 1-5 stop.sh

00 01 * * 6 stop.sh
```

How will this works on Saturday and Sunday? I want to stop the instances on saturday `1am` and start it back on monday `10am`. Is my configuration correct?

from monday to friday it should turn off at 1am and start at morning 10am.

Comment: Running gcloud will no doubt require api keys set as environmental variables. Adding the export of the variable in the script may resolve the issue. But be careful not to make them "world readable" As others have mentioned in their answers, this is not the best way of implementing the solution.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Can you provide what are the variables I need to set to make it work, because I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: Where your server that run the crontab is running? On Prem? On Google Cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crontab` runs as root (!?) and, as such is not authenticated for `gcloud`

There are probably better options but by way of outline of a solution:

- Create a service account with the appropriate permissions to be used by `cron`
- Activate the service account `gcloud auth activate-service-account` for root on the Instance (either during startup or per `cron` task)
- Run the `cron` jobs

### 201126 Update

Apologies, I misread your question and thought you want to run `cron` on a Compute Engine instance too.

I think you want to run `cron` locally.

The trick (!) is to ensure your commands use absolute paths.

```sh
which gcloud
```

For me, this returns `/snap/bin/gcloud` because I'm running on Ubuntu and have `gcloud` installed as a snap. This will likely be different for you.

Then, the following works for me:

`stop.sh`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
INSTANCE=[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
ZONE=[[YOUR-ZONE]]

echo "[$(date --rfc-3339=seconds)] Stopping ${INSTANCE}"

/snap/bin/gcloud compute instances stop ${INSTANCE} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--zone=${ZONE} \
--verbosity=debug

echo "[$(date --rfc-3339=seconds)] Stopped ${INSTANCE}"
```

> **NOTE** I've added [`--verbosity=debug`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity) but you may prefer to reduce or omit this entirely.

Ensure the script is executable:

```sh
chmod +x /path/to/stop.sh
```

Then `crontab -e`:

```
# Stackoverflow: 64994379
* * * * * /path/to/stop.sh >>/path/to/stop.log 2>&1
```

> **NOTE** You want [`30 01 1-31 1-12 1-5`](https://crontab.guru/#30_01_1-31_1-12_1-5) here. This may be simpler as [`30 01 * * 1-5`](https://crontab.guru/#30_01_*_*_1-5)

And:

```
[2020-11-26 09:39:01-08:00] Stopping [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.instances.stop] with arguments: [--project: "[[YOUR-PROJECT]]", --verbosity: "debug", --zone: "[[YOUR-ZONE]]", INSTANCE_NAMES:1: "['[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]']"]
Stopping instance(s) [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]...
......done.
Updated [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[[YOUR-PROJECT]]/zones/[[YOUR-ZONE]]/instances/[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]].
INFO: Display format: "none"
DEBUG: SDK update checks are disabled.
[2020-11-26 09:39:04-08:00] Stopped [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
[2020-11-26 09:40:01-08:00] Stopping [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.instances.stop] with arguments: [--project: "[[YOUR-PROJECT]]", --verbosity: "debug", --zone: "[[YOUR-ZONE]]", INSTANCE_NAMES:1: "['[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]']"]
Stopping instance(s) [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]...
.....done.
Updated [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[[YOUR-PROJECT]]/zones/[[YOUR-ZONE]]/instances/[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]].
INFO: Display format: "none"
DEBUG: SDK update checks are disabled.
[2020-11-26 09:40:04-08:00] Stopped [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
[2020-11-26 09:41:01-08:00] Stopping [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.compute.instances.stop] with arguments: [--project: "[[YOUR-PROJECT]]", --verbosity: "debug", --zone: "[[YOUR-ZONE]]", INSTANCE_NAMES:1: "['[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]']"]
Stopping instance(s) [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]...
......done.
Updated [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[[YOUR-PROJECT]]/zones/[[YOUR-ZONE]]/instances/[[YOUR-INSTANCE]]].
INFO: Display format: "none"
DEBUG: SDK update checks are disabled.
[2020-11-26 09:41:05-08:00] Stopped [[YOUR-INSTANCE]]
```

Google [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) gives you the added benefit of running regardless of whether your host (running `cron`) is running.

You could augment the script to iterate over all your projects and shutdown every instance too if you want to be very diligent. In such a case, it would be good to have the script notify you of its success or failure too in order that you don't become complacent.

Comment: I didn't use `sudo crontab -e` and didn't run as root. I used only `crontab -e`

Comment: Right but you're configuring the daemon and it runs as root.

Comment: I tried running it as root but it didn't work as well. I am trying to shutdown my instances from my local pc at specific time?

Comment: You may be better placed using Google Cloud Scheduler as a `cron` service to do this. See:  https://cloud.google.com/scheduler

Comment: You don't just need to add the task as root but test running it as root. When you `ssh` into an instance, you run as a user account derived from your Google login credentials. If you then use `gcloud` on the instance, you could leverage the same credentials. But, `root` isn't configured for `gcloud` and you'll need to use another `gcloud` user or a service account (better).

Comment: Actually I have configured my gcloud using root also, even then it didnt worked for me.

Comment: You've piqued my curiosity! I'm working on something else currently but I'll try to find some time over the US holiday weekend to try this.

Comment: Thank you! Do let me know if you figure out the issue. If will be of huge help to me.

Comment: You bet! Give me a few days

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer with a solution. Hope that works for you!

Comment: Thank you! I will try it and let you know ASAP.

Comment: Can you check my question once, I have update it with the contents from the log file. I am getting some error

Comment: Remove the `[[` and `]]` from the values. That was just my way of indicating that you should replace the values.

Comment: You just want e.g. `PROJECT="glossy-beach-122457"`

Comment: Oh okay! Sorry, I thought those square brackets were important. Let me try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. Can you please help me with one last doubt regarding crontab setup. I have updated my question bottom part with the details concerning the doubt I am having w.r.t cron job timings.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it's the US Thanksgiving Holiday today and I've been away from the computer. Ok, so you want to start the Instances every weekday at 10:00 and you want to stop the instances at 01:00 Tuesday (stops Monday) through Saturday (stops Friday)? That would be: `00 10 * * 1-5 start.sh` and `00 01 * * 2-6 stop.sh`. I encourage you to trust-but-verify. Set these up and then check them!

Comment: Thank you! I will verify them and Happy Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to follow the official documentation regarding

[Scheduling compute instances with Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule)

> ```
> 1. Compute Engine Instance: A Compute Engine instance we want to run on a
> schedule.
>
> 2.Cloud Functions functions: Functions to start and stop the instance we
> want to schedule.
>
> 3.Pub/Sub messages: Messages sent and received for each start and stop
> event.
>
> 4.Cloud Scheduler jobs: Jobs to make calls on a set schedule to start
> and stop the instance.
> ```

Comment: It feels too much complicated when going through that documentation. I want to do it easy way, I have a local computer and I wanted use `crontab` and use `gcloud` command and schedule two jobs for start and stop compute instances directly from my local pc at specific time

Comment: Then make sure you follow all these steps [Setting up Cron jobs to run bash scripts](https://dev.to/shuaib/setting-up-cron-jobs-to-run-bash-scripts-n5n)

Comment: I did every step mentioned in that blog post, it still didn't worked.